# How do I find the number of triplets (x,y,z) satisfying the given equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality

The question is to find the number of triplets of $(x,y,z)$ satisfying the equation $$x^4+y^4+z^4+1 = 4xyz$$

Clearly, $(1,1,1)$ was pretty trivial.

So I figured trying to use AM-GM might help and I approached as follows

$$\frac{x^4+y^4+z^4+1}{4}\geq (x^4y^4z^4 \times 1)^{1/4}$$
$$\implies x^4+y^4+z^4+1\geq 4xyz$$

And here equality would occur only if $x=y=z$, which again yields $(1,1,1)$ but I end up with some other stuff too...
Putting $x=y=z$ back into the first equation yields

$$3x^4+4x^3=-1$$
$$\implies x^3(3x+4)=-1$$

Now taking cases, $x^3$ and $(3x+4)$ can be $\pm1$ each, yielding 4 cases. But if I take $x^3=-1 $ then that implies that $$x=-1$$, and consequently, $$x=y=z =-1$$, which wont satisfy the equation afterall.

But taking a look again at the original equation, I get $(-1,-1,1), (1,1,-1), (1,-1,-1)$ as other triplets too.

I want to know why I'm getting $x=y=z = -1$ when I use AM-GM. Is it due to the fact that I'm taking x to be negative when infact $x,y,z$ should be +ve for AM-GM to work?

Also, I would like to know how to check if there are any more solutions to this beyond what I have found. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed because you've forgotten to take care of $x,y,z>0$ for AMGM to apply.

Comment: @YiFan Ok....how would I know that there are no more solutions apart from the ones I have found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you realised, we need to consider the signs of $x,y,z$. In this case, this turns out to be quite easy. Notice that $$4xyz=x^4+y^4+z^4+1\geq1>0,$$
so exactly $0$ or $2$ of $x,y,z$ can be negative. In the case none of them are negative we get $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$ as the only solution by AM-GM, by your reasoning which is correct. In case two of them are negative, if they are $x$ and $y$, then substitute $x=-x'$ and $y=-y'$. Then $(x',y',z)$ would be a strictly positive solution to the equation, which by the same reasoning as above must be $(1,1,1)$. So $(x,y,z)$ must be $(-1,-1,1)$. Similarly we get that $(1,-1,-1)$ and $(-1,1,-1)$ are the only other solutions; i.e. there are $4$ solutions overall.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, thank you

Comment: @Techie5879 Glad to help.